# Can't use string as a ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use

Tags: perl

I've been trying to load files out of two folders, `Handlers` and `Games`, that are located in the `System` folder.

It gives me an error

> ```
> Can't use string ("Server/Systems/Handlers/Buddies."...) as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at Server/ClubPenguin.pm line 247`
> ```

Here is the code

```
method loadSystems {

    my @arrHandlers = glob('Server/Systems/Handlers/*.pm');
    my @arrGames    = glob('Server/Systems/Games/*.pm');

    my @arrFiles    = ( @arrHandlers, @arrGames );

    foreach (@arrFiles) {    #Line 247

        foreach my $files ( @{$_} ) {

            my $strClass  = basename( $_, '.pm' );
            my $objSystem = $strClass->new($self);

            $self->{systems}->{$strClass} = $objSystem;
        }
    }

    my $sysCount = scalar( keys %{ $self->{systems} } );

    if ( $sysCount > 0 ) {
        $self->{modules}->{logger}->
                output( 'Successfully Loaded ' . $sysCount . ' Systems', Logger::LEVELS->{inf} );
    }
    else {
        $self->{modules}->{logger}->
                output( 'Failed To Load Any Systems', Logger::LEVELS->{err} );
    }
}
```

Comment: "Can't use string as a HASH ref..." "Can't use string as an ARRAY ref..." Which is it? And what line is the error on?

Comment: I posted it `foreach (@arrFiles) { #Line 247`

Comment: Sorry, missed the comment with the line number. So which error are you actually getting with that code?

Comment: Can't use string ("Server/Systems/Handlers/Buddies."...) as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at Server/ClubPenguin.pm line 247
is the correct error

Comment: Each `$_` is a relative filename ending in `.pm`, not an array reference, so  `@$_` doesn't make any sense. What were you expecting?

Comment: Also, what is `method`? Functions/methods/subroutines are defined with `sub` in Perl.

Comment: `use Method::Signatures;`

Comment: and btw I get this `Can't locate object method "new" via package "Buddies" (perhaps you forgot to load "Buddies"?) at Server/ClubPenguin.pm line 249.` It should work cause there's a file in the Handlers folder with the package Bubbies.

Comment: For future reference, if your code snippet uses modules, it would be useful to include the `use` lines with the code snippet.

Comment: How would that possibly work? You're not loading that module at runtime (at least, not in the code you posted), and I doubt you're loading it at compile time. The error message is pretty clear: _perhaps you forgot to load "Buddies"?_

Comment: I'm using the same exact code but for plugins that retrieves the files from the Plugin folder. It works perfectly fine but the only difference here i'm trying to retrieve files within two folders in the Systems folder

Comment: And, like @smarx mentioned in his [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776715/cant-use-string-as-a-array-ref-while-strict-refs-in-use#comment64925428_38776880), the loading of the module is a separate issue.

Comment: @RyanFuhrman, I doubt that's true. But I think somebody thinks that if they put two arrays another array, they get an array of arrays. But with Perl's automatic flattening, you don't. `my @c = ( @a, @b )` gives you `@c` as a *concatenation* of the elements of `@a` and `@b`. Something funky has to be happening for `foreach my $files (@{$_})` to work on the return from `glob`..

Comment: *"It should work cause there's a file in the Handlers folder with the package `Bubbies`"* Just leaving files lying around doesn't get them loaded. You've misunderstood the code that you're copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that this line

```
my @arrFiles    = ( @arrHandlers, @arrGames );
```

just combines the contents of the two arrays `@arrHandlers` and `@arrGames` intoi a single array. It doesn't create an array of two references, as you seem to expect

You need to write just

```
for ( @arrFiles ) {
    ...
}
```

There's also no need to copy the original arrays, or even to store the result of the `glob` calls. You can write

```
for ( glob 'Server/Systems/{Handlers,Games}/*.pm' ) {
    ...
}
```

with the same effect

Answer (score 0):

I think you need just this:

```
foreach (@arrFiles) {
    my $strClass = basename($_, '.pm');
    my $objSystem = $strClass->new($self);
    $self->{systems}->{$strClass} = $objSystem;
}
```

Comment: I get this error `Can't locate object method "new" via package "Buddies" (perhaps you forgot to load "Buddies"?) at Server/ClubPenguin.pm line 249.`

Comment: I'm not sure that relates to the issue at hand here. The issue in your code is that the comma concatenated your list, so you just need one loop to iterate over all the elements.

Comment: You probably need to `require` the modules you find? `require $_;` perhaps?

Comment: well I use package Namehere;

Comment: Anyway, this is off-topic. Ask a new question if you want help with this new issue.